# Next.js server - creating a 404 catcher that redirects back to "/Home" route

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm new to Next.js and have written a website containing a few pages (that correspond to different paths).
I understand that Next automatically directs each page inside the "pages" directory (for example ".../Home" to the Home.js file if it's inside the pages dir). If the page doesn't exist it returns a 404 response.
I read [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error) that you can override that error page with pages/404.js, but I want to redirect the user to the "/Home" path instead.

I tried using redirect from 'next/navigation' to redirect inside the custom 404 js file:

```
// pages/404.js
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Custom404() {
  redirect("/Contact");
//   return <h1>404 - Page Not Found HI!</h1>;
}
```

but no success there - I got the error saying "Error: NEXT_REDIRECT This error happened while generating the page."

I also tried creating "next.config.js" and catch all paths other then "Home" but again no success as it got redirected too many times...

```
export async function redirects() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/Home",
      destination: "/Home",
      permanent: false,
    },
    {
      source: "/:otherPath",
      destination: "/Home",
      permanent: false,
    },
  ];
}
```

Does anyone know an elegant way of redirecting with Next.js that catches all pages that aren't inside "pages" dir?
Many thanks!